# Expressjs session timeout

Tags: node.js, session

I have defined my session in express (v3) as follows:

```
app.use(express.session());
```

My understanding is that since I have not specified the maxAge or expires property, they will hold `null` values and thus the session will never timeout.

However, users are reporting that the session does time out - the user may or may not be working on the application - they may log in, go for lunch or something like that and when they are back, any action causes them to be redirected to the login page - that is they are logged out after period of inactivity.

What more should I do to prevent this? Even if user is inactive, the session should not timeout.

Comment: If you are restarting the server, that would delete their session - unless you're using something like [connect-redis](https://github.com/visionmedia/connect-redis).

Comment: By default cookies are used to store the session, so use the console to inpect the cookies and see how they are set.

Comment: @Wex No, I am not restarting the server.